# Applying patch config files to a local XM Cloud Docker environment

Tags: docker, xm-cloud, patch-configuration

I'm doing some XM Cloud experiments. Based on the starter kit I've got it running local with Docker: https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head

There is also a Nextjs project which uses GraphQL. When running `jss bootstrap` I get this error: ['jss bootstrap' causes JavaScript heap out of memory error on graphql-let step](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/31654/jss-bootstrap-causes-javascript-heap-out-of-memory-error-on-graphql-let-step)

The fix is a patch config with some changes: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/31669/3309

Does anyone know how I can do this local for XM Cloud? Since it's running in Docker I can't just change any config files or add a patch file. There is a readme file in the starter kit, but a publish doesn't seem to be working: https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head/blob/main/src/platform/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To patch you config file you can prepare folder structure as `\App_Config\Include\z.Services.GraphQL\z.Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeContent.config`.

As mentioned in read me it is XP0 container topology and thus only has a Standalone cm so you need to place it under `ClonedfolderPath\docker\deploy\platform\` directory. `platform folder` is a cm container.

Try this patch file `z.Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeContent.config`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore>
        <api>
            <GraphQL>
                <!-- the defaults section contains config templates that can be reused elsewhere using 'ref' -->
                <defaults>
                    <content>
                        <schemaProviders>
                            <edgeContent type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.EdgeSchemaProvider, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema">
                            <templates type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardTemplatePredicate, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">
                            <database>$(1)</database>
                            <!-- Only include our JSS application -->
                            <paths hint="list:AddIncludedPath">
                            <foundation>
                                <patch:delete />
                            </foundation>
                            <feature>
                                <patch:delete />
                            </feature>
                            <project>
                                <patch:delete />
                            </project>
                            <userdefined>
                                <patch:delete />
                            </userdefined>
                            <jssSite>/sitecore/templates/Project/OurJssSite</jssSite>
                            </paths>                 
                            </templates>

                             </edgeContent>
                        </schemaProviders>
                    </content>
                </defaults>
            </GraphQL>
        </api>
         </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

then run `.\up.ps1`

Hope it helps!

Comment: That worked! Thank you for this example. I tried something similar myself, but somehow my Docker container got unhealthy after that. The above example does work!

Answer (score 1):

In your repo, you will see that there is a VS Solution file and a VS project file.

The project is under `/src/platform/Platform.vsproj`

This platform project is built and layered into your XM Cloud CM image in docker, it is also built and layered into your XM Cloud CM image in the cloud when you deploy.

To patch Sitecore config, you can simply create your patch file and add it to that project under the normal location `/App_Config/Include/<your folder>`

Once you have added, you will either need to rebuild your containers, or just publish the VS Project to the deploy location, by default this is `<repo root>/docker/build/platform`

Comment: Thanks I tried to publish from VS, but somehow the file didn't end up in the \docker\deploy\platform\ folder.